# Firebase REST API - authenticating request with id token doesn't work

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a Unity C# project and trying to authenticate a request to Realtime Database using the id token Firebase returns after a user signs in, but it says the request is unauthorized. Here's my sign-in code (`AuthResponse` wraps the response body):

```
WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField("email", email);
form.AddField("password", password);

using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=" + API_KEY, form))
{
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Login failed: {www.error}");
        callback(false);
    }
    else
    {
        AuthResponse data = www.downloadHandler.text.FromJson<AuthResponse>();
        ID_TOKEN = data.idToken;
    }
}
```

And my read request:

```
string url = $"{DATABASE_URL}{path}.json";
if (auth) url += $"?auth={ID_TOKEN}";
using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
{
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Read failed: {www.error}");
    }
}
```

My database has public rules and everything works without the `auth` parameter. What am I missing?

**Edit:** This is the token response:

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#SignInWithPasswordResponse",
  "localId": <LOCAL_ID>,
  "email": <EMAIL>,
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": <ID_TOKEN>,
  "registered": true
}
```

This is the full read request url: `https://<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseio.com/testing/flatString.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>`

Comment: Sou you successfully get a id token and the read request failes?

Comment: @crysxd seems like it. I've printed out the id token and nothing looks wrong with it. It also doesn't seem to expire (`expiresIn` is empty).

Comment: I fired up a request to sign in anonymously I had lying around and got [this response](https://gist.github.com/crysxd/1c482a4e72dbb915a1a8eabbaa901a5b). It should very similar to yours. Can you compare it? Adding to the token to your database URL is fine as you do it. Can you post a more complete example of the URL you are requesting and the token response? One of them is likely to be the cause

Comment: @crysxd updated with token response and request url

Comment: I think public rules using for client with pub/sub. Mark the rules read/write: false or whatever you want for pub/sub. If you want to using with API, send token as you do, then verify it in firebase server by manual.

Comment: @tuledev I might be misinterpreting, but my database already has public rules, and I'm posting to the RTDB, not a custom backend (which as far as I'm aware is the main use case for manually verifying id tokens).

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing your own httppost  use Firebase Unity SDK

Before you can use Firebase Authentication, you need to:

Register your Unity project and configure it to use Firebase.

If your Unity project already uses Firebase, then it's already registered and configured for Firebase.

If you don't have a Unity project, you can download a sample app.

Add the Firebase Unity SDK (specifically, FirebaseAuth.unitypackage) to your Unity project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm purposefully using the REST API instead of the SDK because I want to build for desktop.